# Export RadGrid with CSS Style

Tags: radgrid, export-to-pdf

Iam Trying to Export my RadGrid to Pdf in the same CSS Style of the Grid...

here is my approach:

```
<ExportSettings IgnorePaging="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
   <Pdf PageHeight="162mm" PageWidth="600mm" PageTitle="Payment Orders" DefaultFontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" Title="Payment Orders"
                PageBottomMargin="50mm" PageTopMargin="35mm" PageLeftMargin="150mm" PageRightMargin="50mm" Author="AbdanSoftware" PaperSize="A4" />
</ExportSettings>
```

Any way from Code-behing or ClientSide to do it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set export settings for you RadGrid like so:

```
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.FileName = "File Name"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = True
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageHeight="162mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageWidth="600mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageTitle="Payment Orders"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.DefaultFontFamily="Arial Unicode MS"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.Title="Payment Orders"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageBottomMargin="50mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageTopMargin="35mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageLeftMargin="150mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageRightMargin="50mm"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.Author="AbdanSoftware"
RadGrid1.ExportSettings.Pdf.PaperSize="A4"
```

**Edit:** To include css in your export you can do so in the `HTMLExporting` event for Word and Excel formats. **For PDF exporting only inline styles are applied**.

```
Private Sub RadGrid1_HTMLExporting(sender As Object, e As Telerik.Web.UI.GridHTMLExportingEventArgs) Handles RadGrid1.HTMLExporting
    Dim css As String = "body { color: red; }"
    e.Styles.Append(css)
End Sub
```

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-html-export.html) for more help on Word/Excel export, and [this documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-pdf-export.html) for PDF export help.

Comment: You got me wrong ... the ExportSettings in my question code doesn't have a property to export Grid with the same grid CSS.. So Is there is any way to Import my grid CSS and apply it to the Exported Pdf file also....